# How do I join four tables together?

Tags: sql

I have to join four tables together and am having trouble. My query as it stands is returning data, but it's not the data I need. I do not think I have all four tables joined together correctly. How would I join the tables properly? Thank you.

Justin

I need to join the `CXADMIN.RO_FAILURE_DTL RF`, `CXADMIN.RO_HIST RH`, `saadmin.sa_repair_part@elgsad rp`, and `saadmin.sa_code_group_task_dtl @ELGSAD cg` tables together.

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     RF.REPAIR_ORD,
     RH.RECV_UNIT,
     RH.RECV_SERIAL_NBR,
     rf.created_date,
     RP.FAULT_CODE,
     RP.REPAIR_ACTION_CODE,
     cg.task_code
FROM
    CXADMIN.RO_FAILURE_DTL RF,
    CXADMIN.RO_HIST RH,
    saadmin.sa_repair_part@elgsad rp,
    saadmin.sa_code_group_task_dtl @ELGSAD cg
WHERE
    RF.REPAIR_ORD = RH.REPAIR_ORD
    and Rp.REPAIR_ORD = cg.REPAIR_ORD
    AND RF.FAILURE_CODE ='DISK'
    AND RH.CURR_FACILITY_ID ='23'
    AND RF.CREATED_DATE >'1-JUN-2010'
    AND RF.CREATED_DATE <  '1-dec-2010'
    AND (CG.TASK_CODE ='PHMD'
         OR CG.TASK_CODE ='PHSN'
         OR CG.TASK_CODE ='CHMD'
         OR  CG.TASK_CODE ='CHSN')
```

Comment: You need to specify the join condition for (RH or RF) to (RP or CG)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL query on multiple databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931652/sql-query-on-multiple-databases)

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931652/sql-query-on-multiple-databases/5931791#5931791) to your previous question. Included both ansi-86 and ANSI-92 style joins

Answer (score 2):

Your code is essentially doing a Cross-join but it looks like what you want to do is an inner join.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 RF.REPAIR_ORD,
 RH.RECV_UNIT,
 RH.RECV_SERIAL_NBR,
 rf.created_date,
 RP.FAULT_CODE,
 RP.REPAIR_ACTION_CODE,
 cg.task_code
FROM CXADMIN.RO_FAILURE_DTL RF
  INNER JOIN CXADMIN.RO_HIST RH ON RF.REPAIR_ORD = RH.REPAIR_ORD
  INNER JOIN saadmin.sa_repair_part@elgsad rp ON RF.REPAIR_ORD = rp.REPAIR_ORD
  INNER JOIN saadmin.sa_code_group_task_dtl @ELGSAD cg ON RF.REPAIR_ORD = cg.REPAIR_ORD
WHERE
 AND RF.FAILURE_CODE ='DISK'
 AND RH.CURR_FACILITY_ID ='23'
 AND RF.CREATED_DATE >'1-JUN-2010'
 AND RF.CREATED_DATE <  '1-dec-2010'
 AND (CG.TASK_CODE ='PHMD'
     OR CG.TASK_CODE ='PHSN'
     OR CG.TASK_CODE ='CHMD'
     OR  CG.TASK_CODE ='CHSN')
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few standards issues that you aren't complying with, but minus those I see one issue. You are starting from RF, and you've established your join condition on RH with

```
RF.REPAIR_ORD = RH.REPAIR_ORD
```

Then you've established your join condition from RP to CG with

```
Rp.REPAIR_ORD = cg.REPAIR_ORD
```

However, (and I'm guessing here) I believe you need to establish your condition from RF to RP with

```
RF.REPAIR_ORD = RP.REPAIR_ORD
```

The standards issues I was talking about, is that you can clean it up a little bit and make the SP look as follows, notice the updated JOIN section

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     RF.REPAIR_ORD,
     RH.RECV_UNIT,
     RH.RECV_SERIAL_NBR,
     rf.created_date,
     RP.FAULT_CODE,
     RP.REPAIR_ACTION_CODE,
     cg.task_code
FROM
    CXADMIN.RO_FAILURE_DTL RF
    JOIN CXADMIN.RO_HIST RH  ON RF.REPAIR_ORD = RH.REPAIR_ORD
    JOIN saadmin.sa_repair_part@elgsad rp ON RP.REPAIR_ORD = RH.REPAIR_ORD
    JOIN saadmin.sa_code_group_task_dtl @ELGSAD cg ON Rp.REPAIR_ORD = cg.REPAIR_ORD
WHERE
    RF.FAILURE_CODE ='DISK'
    AND RH.CURR_FACILITY_ID ='23'
    AND RF.CREATED_DATE >'1-JUN-2010'
    AND RF.CREATED_DATE <  '1-dec-2010'
    AND (CG.TASK_CODE ='PHMD'
         OR CG.TASK_CODE ='PHSN'
         OR CG.TASK_CODE ='CHMD'
         OR  CG.TASK_CODE ='CHSN')
```

Comment: The query isn't non-standard, it just uses an older standard. There was no `join` keyword in the beginning.

Comment: @Guffa - You're correct. Although now that I'm looking into it, it appears that at least the outer join implicit syntax is deprecated, and some sources make it appear as though the inner join implicit syntax is also deprecated, though it's not very clear. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172122.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It would be really, really useful if you could show some sample data...

But without that, it looks like your joining CXADMIN.RO_FAILURE_DTL RF to 
    CXADMIN.RO_HIST RH, and sa_repair_part@elgsad to sa_code_group_task_dtl, but I can't see how you're joining those two groups together. So, basically, you should be getting two queries, cross-joined together; the distinct clause is just reducing the number of cross joins, but not really helping.

Answer (score 1):

I generally suggest using the format

FROM table t1
LEFT|INNER JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.colname = t2.colname

Rather than

FROM table1, table2.

I'd try the following joins and see if it works better for you.

FROM CXADMIN.RO_FAILURE_DTL RF
INNER JOIN CXADMIN.RO_HIST RH
  ON RF.REPAIR_ORD = RH.REPAIR_ORD
INNER JOIN saadmin.sa_repair_part@elgsad rp
  ON ?
INNER JOIN saadmin.sa_code_group_task_dtl @ELGSAD cg
 ON Rp.REPAIR_ORD = cg.REPAIR_ORD

It appears you're missing an ON clause for RP to the rest of your tables.  That might be the issue you're having.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select
    --
    -- your columns here
    --
FROM CXADMIN.RO_FAILURE_DTL                as rf
join CXADMIN.RO_HIST                       as rh on rh.REPAIR_ORD = rf.REPAIR_ORD
join saadmin.sa_repair_part@elgsad         as rp on rp.REPAIR_ORD = rf.REPAIR_ORD
join saadmin.sa_code_group_task_dtl@ELGSAD as cg on cg.REPAIR_ORD = rf.REPAIR_ORD
WHERE RF.FAILURE_CODE ='DISK'
  AND RH.CURR_FACILITY_ID ='23'
  AND RF.CREATED_DATE >'1-JUN-2010'
  AND RF.CREATED_DATE <  '1-dec-2010'
  AND CG.TASK_CODE in ('PHMD', 'PHSN', 'CHMD', 'CHSN')
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA.a inner join TABLEB.b ON TABLEB.b = TABLEA.a inner join TABLEB.c ON TABLEB.C = TABLEA.b inner join TABLEB.d ON TABLEB.d = TABLEA.c WHERE TABLEA.id !="";
```