# Need an SQL query to connect table in two different databases

Tags: sql-server-2008

Need an SQL query to connect the two tables in the different databases but in the same server.

Comment: a little search could have given you a solution. [search result](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+query+on+multiple+databases) ... ( like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931652/sql-query-on-multiple-databases) )

Comment: just prefix your tables correctly (`<db>.<schema>.<table_name>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
 'SELECT a.userID, b.usersFirstName, b.usersLastName  FROM databaseA.dbo.TableA a inner join database B.dbo.TableB b  ON a.userID=b.userID'
```

[Reference]  (http://forums.asp.net/t/1254974.aspx?How+to+join+tables+from+different+databases+in+SQL+select+statement+)

[Refernce 2] (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1e6d7732-aa67-4069-b373-d7220dc251aa/merge-two-tables-from-different-databases?forum=vblanguage)

Comment: Thanks Eldho the query works,and i also need the query to connect the tables and database that are in different server

Comment: User try this [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145637/querying-data-by-joining-two-tables-in-two-database-on-different-servers)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Databasename1.dbo.tablename1 A
inner join  Databasename2.dbo.tablename1 B
on A.ID=B.ID
```

or

```
 select A.*,B.* from Databasename1.dbo.tablename1 A
    inner join  Databasename2.dbo.tablename1 B
    on A.ID=B.ID
```

or

```
 select A.columnname1,B.columnname2 from Databasename1.dbo.tablename1 A
inner join  Databasename2.dbo.tablename1 B
on A.ID=B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

> select 
>   D1.Field1, 
>   D2.Field2
>
> from Database1.dbo.TableofD1 D1
>
> inner
>   join Database2.dbo.TableofD2 D2
>   on D1.fieldmain=D2.fieldmain