# Connecting three or more databases

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have three or more MSSQL Database's tables. I wanna  collect information from them in a table , but I haven't an idea. How can I solve it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please take a look at [help] in particular to [ask]

Comment: [SQL query on multiple databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931652/sql-query-on-multiple-databases)

Comment: I suggest investigating the variations of the `join` keyword. A lot of the time it is used in combination with `AS`. That should get you started on the right path as far as research is concerned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new table with amount of fields(and them datatypes) which you need from other tables, then create INSERT query in which you pass SELECT query from 3 tables as VALUES.
This page may be helpful with examples: [INSERT Examples (Transact-SQL)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381(v=sql.105).aspx#OtherTables)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Web.config File

Type

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DB1" connectionString=server.;database=DB1>
    <add name="DB2" connectionString=server.;database=DB2>
</connectionStrings>
```

Then go to aspx file and drag and drop Grid view from Toobox

Use header files such as

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Then write the following code

```
string name1= ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB1"].ConnectionString;
string name2= ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB2"].ConnectionString;

Sqlconnection con=new sqlconnection(name1);
sqladapter da=new sqladapter("select * from table1",con);

dataset ds1=new dataset();
da.fill(ds1);

con=new sqlconnection(name2);
da.SelectCommand.connection=con;

dataset ds2=new dataset();
da.fill(ds2);

ds1.merge(ds2);
GridView1.Datasource= ds1;
GridView1.DataBind();
```