# How to make LookupSet display results in many rows

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have 2 datasets

First one looks up for contactID, ContactMethod and Name (dataset1)

```
         ContactId | ContactMethod | Name
           1048    |  email@email.ca |   John Doe
```

Second looks up for contactID, deliveries, and deliveryStatus

```
          ContactID | deliveries | deliveryStatus
             1048   |  FailedAttempt | Undeliverable
             1048   |  FailedAttempt | Undeliverable
             1048   |  FailedAttempt | Undeliverable
```

and repeat that 6 more times...

I know I could do one single query but those two datasets reside in two different database so I can't make one query with 2 datasource ( as far as I know. I could be totally wrong)

So here's my function

```
 =Join(LookUpSet(Fields!ContactMethod.Value, 
                 Fields!ContactMethod.Value,
                 Fields!CoarseReportingBucketName.Value,
                 "EX_JobDeliveries"), 
            ",")
```

This will return me, in one cell:( if you see the picture in the link, undeliverable is in one cell 9 times)

[image]

How would I go about in displaying all these results in different cells, unless there's another way. Using Lookup only returns row, I was hoping it would automatically fill itself, but it doesn't.

So the result would look something like this ( so a stepped report)

```
  ContactMethod | Name | deliveries | deliveryStatus
  email@email.ca|
                John Doe | 
                         FailedAttempt | Undeliverable
                         FailedAttempt | Undeliverable
                         FailedAttempt | Undeliverable
```

and 6 more times of that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Environment.NewLine` in the join function:

```
 =Join(LookUpSet(Fields!ContactMethod.Value, 
                 Fields!ContactMethod.Value,
                 Fields!CoarseReportingBucketName.Value,
                 "EX_JobDeliveries"), 
            Environment.NewLine)
```

If you need to show each value in a row of your tablix/matrix you will have to modify your dataset query.

Also note you can perform a query across different databases (even in different servers).

```
SELECT firstdb.*, seconddb.*
FROM Server1.Database1.dbo.myTable AS firstdb
INNER JOIN Server2.Database2.dbo.myTable AS seconddb
   ON firstdb.id = seconddb.id
```

TAKEN FROM [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5931685/2647648)

Despite it is possible you face issues with the collation between both servers it is the only way to get your expected result. There is no way to generate rows from SSRS expressions.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Sorry if this wasn't clear, I do need a new row in my tablix. I'm doing it as a stepped report. I could probably "get away" with doing a new line, but I'd like to try to add a new row. When I pull my "EX_JobDeliveries" in SSMS, the query returns 9 values, so I was hoping doing a simple Lookup(Expression) would return the 9 values like a regular expression would, but I seem to be lacking somewhere.

Comment: Oh, for the two database query : good to know. Though, wouldn't this create issues with SSRS where I have to chose a datasource. I.e query server1 and server2 and then chose datasource of server1

Comment: @Pepe. You can link a server A to server B, - check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx) - then just add a datasource to server B from you can access server A. Try it first in SSMS then when your query works just create the datasource and dataset in Report Builder.

Comment: Thank you :) I'll create a new query at this point to make it look like I want it. Thanks a lot :)